# Difference between Slack Bot User OAuth Token and Bot access token?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-bot

I created a slack bot app. Now I am trying to figure out the difference between Bot User OAuth Token and Bot access token.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same thing! There's more information about the token types on the documentation site: https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types